# Better job scheduler

Tags: spring-batch, job-scheduling

We are trying to implement a few batch jobs using Spring Batch. Our application is batch heavy, currently, we have jobs in shell scripts. Now, we are trying to move to spring batch. We are looking for a scheduler with monitors.

We are evaluating various schedulers like Spring Cloud Data Flow, Airflow, Argo
We are checking the feasibility of these jobs running on both Kubernetes/OpenShift

We are not sure which one is good, can someone suggest which we would go for?

Things we expect:

1. List batch jobs in which stage along with logs
2. Monitor jobs (Dynatrace/Prometheus)
3. Complex cron jobs scheduling (more flexibility similar to that of unix cron jobs)

Comment: Move your question to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . You may need to add more details to comply with their rules.  On SO such questions are out of scope.

Comment: sure thanks, I have added it there.